# AWS Lambda ARN format for an Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Running my java alexa skill on Lambda.  Am experimenting with Lambda provisioned concurrency as the lambda startup time makes my skill respond very slowly.  My question pertains to the ARN I set in `AWS Lambda ARN -> Endpoint` in the alexa developer console.

Lambda gives me multiple options for ARN:

1. `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:abc:function:SWBlue` without an app version
2. `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:abc:function:SWBlue:5` with an app version

When using 1, which app version will be invoked?  the latest?
Assuming provisioned concurrency is enabled on the latest app version, will that still take effect when using 1?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke a function using an unqualified ARN, Lambda implicitly invokes $LATEST.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html
So 1. should call latest version. You might want to increase memory if your change doesn't help. Java needs to setup Java Virtual Machine (JVM) before it can run for the first time. This is likely why the first interaction is delayed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-memory-console

Answer (score 0):

Only concerning slow start up times

Which programming language do you use?
If you use java try Snap Start: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/snapstart.html

I got improvements in cold startup times with GraalVM Native image because Snap Start didn't exist at this time.